# What version of Unity 5.5 SDK and Java do I need to export to apk?

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine

What version of Unity 5.5 SDK and Java do I need to export to apk?

I am having problems exporting to apk with this outdated version of unity.

I can't find any information about it.

I downloaded the latest Android studio, I put the path to its sdk in unity but I get error

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to resolve build tools directory. See the console for more details. 
C:\Program Files -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users//AppData/Local/Android/Sdktools" -Dfile. encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:/Users//AppData/Local/Android/Android/Sdktools/Sdktools.jar" -Dfile. encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:/Users//AppData/Local/Android/Sdktools.jar" -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users//AppData/Local/Android/Sdktools.jar" -Dcom.
```

I have found android sdk 24.03 and java 8, but in unity 5.5 I put the address where it is unzipped and nothing, it asks for a valid path again.

https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-build-tools.html#google_vignette